# Is there a way to use 'else' as a modifier in Perl 'if' constructs (like for 'if')?

Tags: perl

I have seen

```
if(cond) {} elsif(cond2) {} else {}
statement if(cond)
unless(cond) {}
```

But is there a

```
statement if(cond)
statement2 elsif(cond)
statement3 else
```

and

```
if(cond) {}
elsun(cond){} # un meaning else unless
```

Comment: Related: [Should I use Perl's conditional ? : operator as a switch/case statement or instead of if/elsif?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3898836/133939)

Comment: `unless` = `if not`... There is no need for `elsun`, `elsif not` will suffice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, see [perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements).

Comment: This not much more than a link-only answer. Can you summarise here?

Comment: Summarize? It's not part of the language, so "No" is about as summarized as you can get. There's nothing to point to because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is only the first.

Trailing `if` modifier is probably more accurately shown as:

```
statement if cond
```

That is, there's no need for parentheses around the condition (since they're not needed for disambiguation).

Comment: Isn't there a more official name for it (than "trailing if")? 'Programming Perl' has "...if and unless modifiers" (page 130). Statement modifier?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much:

```
print "foo\n" if ($foo eq $bar);
```

is a shortcut for

```
if ($foo eq $bar) {
    print "foo\n";
}
```

And, I rarely use the previous because in the second example, the `if` statement is more obvious than in the first example. The only time I've used the postfixed `if` is something like this:

```
next if ($line =~ /^\s*$/);
```

That's usually short enough to catch.

You might want to try:

```
use Switch;
switch ($val) {
    case 1          { print "number 1" }
    case "a"        { print "string a" }
    case [1..10,42] { print "number in list" }
    case (\@array)  { print "number in list" }
    case /\w+/      { print "pattern" }
    case qr/\w+/    { print "pattern" }
    case (\%hash)   { print "entry in hash" }
    case (\&sub)    { print "arg to subroutine" }
    else            { print "previous case not true" }
}
```

which is what I think you really are looking for. BTW, I've had problems with `Switch` and it doesn't work with *older* versions of Perl (pre Perl 5.8).